# Multiple Compaction Activities creating load on Cassandra Nodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Some of Nodes in our PROD cluster goes **Yellow**, **RED** or even **Grey** because of high load. But nodes are still working.

**Timeout during this time comes in Bulk.**

All of this happen during Compaction activities running on this node.

**Is there a way to control Auto Compaction activities for a keyspace or control whole compaction & run them on weekend during idle time??**

This will give relief to Production nodes during Business hours.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple reasons for high load. it may be due to high TPS on cassandra cluster. compaction is a heavy process and it requires at least 50% disk space for healthy compaction if using STCS compaction strategy. you can also check concurrent_read/cassandra_write in cassandra.yaml and tune it. Also,you can tune your heap if using G1GC. we can tune compactionthroughput with respect to system configuration.we can disable auto compaction by nodetool disableautocompaction but it is not recommended on prod cluster. auto comaction must be enabled to reclaim disk space. upgrade cassandra cluster if you are using lower version of cassandra.higher version is giving better performance as I am using 3.11.2 and 3.11.3.